# adding simple countdown (as numbers) to my php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have php page that i want to run simple countdown 60 seconds in a certain area of my page (in the footer) because i have auto refresh code to refresh the page every 60 seconds so i want to show to users that 60, 59, 58, 57.... just a text rolling countdown until it refreshes so it will start again. easy and simple, no need for complete count down scripts as shown online in many sites...

what i could think is a gif animated small icon, that can work but if possible not add an image is better, i just want normal size text as numbers running from 60 to 0 then looping again (even if no looping is fine... page will be refreshed anyway)

what to do?

Comment: Use javascript, PHP can't give you the functionality you want as it runs server side, not client side..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with PHP since it is server side . You can create using javascript. Please try this code:

```
<div id="timer">##</div>
<button id="starter" onclick="start('60');">start</button>
<script>
var tme = document.getElementById("timer");
var bt= document.getElementById("starter");
var counting = false;

function start(count) {
    //console.log(counting);
    if (!counting) {
        counting = true;
        tme.innerHTML = count;
        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            if (count >= 0) {
                tme.innerHTML = count;
                count--;
            } else {
                clearInterval(timer);
                count = arguments[0];
                counting = false;
            }
        }, 400);
    }
}
</script>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: well, i guess this will work, but not for my case...  or maybe i am lacking the way of doing it :(